# How to only have 3 checkboxes per line dynamically in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

How to only have 3 checkboxes per line dynamically in JavaScript. Currently this is what I have right now.
[image]

And I want it would be like this.
[image]

I've tried different ways but couldn't find a solution for this.

Comment: please share your code or example how you are adding

Answer (score 0):

you could try with grid

div row is the grid with 3 cols 1fr.

you can add number of div you want, it'll be always 3 cols

you can put the div row inside a container.

```css
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.input {
  background-color: rgba(89, 3, 76, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="input">
    <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
    <label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input">
    <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="Car">
    <label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input">
    <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="Boat">
    <label for="vehicle3"> I have a boat</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input">
    <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle4" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
    <label for="vehicle4"> I have a bike</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input">
    <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle5" name="vehicle2" value="Car">
    <label for="vehicle5"> I have a car</label>
  </div>
</div>
```